# General purpose translations collection

Tags: translation, multilingual

Is anybody know a free collection of general purpose simple phrase transaltions for different languages?

I mean, is there any multi language database with simple phrases like "Yes", "No", "Forgot password?", "Resend email", "Sign up", etc?

Maybe just the way i search is wrong, but that kind of database is would be handy for anyone who want to go (let's say) a website multilingual. But I can't find one.

Ok, actually i find some by searching for "multilingual phrase collection" eg.: http://www.uazone.org/multiling/unilang/index.html but it's has only 20 phases and not a database (not structured to process programmically)

Comment: Meanwhile I started to collect .po files from deb packages (apt-file search .po | grep -P "\\.po$") and processing into a database.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the [OPUS project](http://opus.nlpl.eu/) from the University of Helsinki collecting multilingual sentences has data from [GNOME](http://opus.nlpl.eu/GNOME.php) [KDE](http://opus.nlpl.eu/KDE4.php) [Ubuntu](http://opus.nlpl.eu/Ubuntu.php) and [OpenOffice](http://opus.nlpl.eu/OpenOffice.php) (plus plenty of other sources like movie subtitles or EU legislation).